# Is it possible to find determinant of a matrix by given the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

If I already found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a particular matrix , is there an easy way to find the  determinant of that matrix ?

Comment: the product of all eigenvalues will give you the det.

Comment: Yes @DanielAkech, thank you. I can't fix so I'll erase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is as follows

$\det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^N \lambda_i$,

where $\lambda_i$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue of the matrix. The formula follows from the definition of the matrix characteristic equation $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$.